# "Cannot find module " despite file being available

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to import my helper functions in my express app index.js. Imported it. Now it is throwing Error

```
[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'F:\RnD\express-boilerplate\src\helpers\error' imported from F:\RnD\express-boilerplate\src\index.js
```

My index.js:

```
import express from "express";

import { ErrorHandler, handleError } from "./helpers/error";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world");
});

app.get("/error", (req, res) => {
  throw new ErrorHandler(500, "My Bad");
});

app.use((req, res) => {
  throw new ErrorHandler(404, "Not found");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  handleError(err, res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("App starting in PORT: 3000");
});
```

My error.js:

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(statusCode, message) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

const handleError = (err, res) => {
  const { statusCode, message } = err;
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: "error",
    statusCode,
    message,
  });
};

export { ErrorHandler, handleError };
```

I have checked location multiple times. Location is accurate. But why it is showing cannot find module?
I am using node version 19.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the behavior of EcmaScript, you need to specify the file extension, read more about it here [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions).

Update the second line of index.js, where you are importing modules as

```js
import { ErrorHandler, handleError } from "./helpers/error.js";
```

Answer (score 0):

in the 2nd line  of main file make it

```js
import { ErrorHandler, handleError } from "./helpers/error.js";
```